# private property of my class is null

Tags: java, swing

I've the follow code: http://aiids.pastebin.com/aLGYjraC

The problem is on line 84 it gives me a NullPointerException on programmaBesteller. When I debug, every private member (JMenu and JMenuItem) are null :s.

I don't see the problem because I do **new DefaultMenuBar()**...

Comment: sounds wierd. it there any exception while creation of this object ?

Comment: No :s He calls the constructor like he should be but when I'm inspecting the object, all the private members are null.

Comment: Where is `buildMenuProgramma` called from?  The superclass?  If so, that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which I think demonstrates the problem you are having:

```
public abstract class Super {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub();
    }

    public Super() {
        printMe();
    }

    abstract void printMe();

    private static class Sub extends Super {

        private final Object x = new Object();

        public Sub() {
            super();
            printMe();
        }

        @Override
        protected void printMe() {
            System.out.println("printMe: " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
printMe: null
printMe: java.lang.Object@1fee6fc
```

ie, the field `x`, which is explicitly initialised and looks like it cannot be `null` is not actually initialised at the time of the superclass constructor.  Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe *buildMenuProgramma* method is called from the superclass constructor? Those fields are not yet instantiated on that phase.

Comment: I call the method build() and that method calls the abstract methods like buildMenuProgramma.

Comment: There is no method build() in your pasted code.  I cannot see any explanation for these fields being null unless the `buildMenuProgramma` is called from within `super()`.  We need to see the superclass code to be any more help.

Comment: As I understand, `build()` method is, indeed, called from superclass' constructor. If so, you can simply create another abstract method to instantiate all the private members and call it before all the others.